# How to login with new IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I can not login with new IAM user who has console access: 
[image]

I have downloaded credentials and when trying to login using given console url(`https://My_AWS_Account_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/`) and I  am receiving following error:

> Your authentication information is incorrect. Please try again.

This is a policy summary for user:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "my-s3-arn"
        }
    ]
}`

I have tried to manage and change password for this user and to login again but the same error appears:
[image]

Any idea how to login or troubleshout problem?

Comment: Did you wait a few minutes and then try it again?

Comment: I have just tried again and the same error.

Comment: Does it have permissions to access the console? Could be user was created only with programmatical access.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this user is not having the permissions for accessing AWS console, While creating user you need to select the access type for **AWS Management Console Access** that will provide the username and select the custom password that you can decide on console directly and also give below permissions just for testing.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem in the past, usually when the IAM user was added recently. The two ways to overcome this were to wait a day or two and try the credentials again or change the password manually (not using automatically generated passwords).