# AWS IAM error : 'Your authentication information is incorrect. Please try again'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am getting the error after I create an IAM user with `AdministratorAccess` or `AmazonEC2FullAccess`:

> Your authentication information is incorrect. Please try again

I was able to create a user without a problem two weeks ago, while having active users. Now adding more new users gives me this error. 
I have tried creating new users using `Copy permissions from existing user` too but these new users also error out. ([Picture of aws iam steps taken with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AneA.png))

I apologize if this is a duplicate but an answer to a previous post of [how to log in with new iam user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273372/how-to-login-with-new-iam-user) did not solve my issue. I added

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

to inline policy JSON for this user but it still did not help.

Answer (score 17):

I end up switching to use Autogenerated password option and my users are now able to get in.  retest using the custom password and it's working now too.  Something must of gotten fix on AWS.

Comment: it worked for me as well, switching to use Auto-generated password option

Comment: 1 year later (mid-december 2019) the issue still prevails, and this solution still works. unbelievably unprofessional on amazon's account.

Comment: still relevant in July 2020

Comment: Something wrong AWS end. I changed my root account password four times, still during login, I get "Your authentication information is incorrect. Please try again"

Comment: Still relevant May 2021

Comment: Still relevant November 2021

Comment: Still relevant in December 2021

Comment: Having this problem in November 2022, but the proposed solution didn't work for me =(

Comment: Still relevant in Nov 2023. I have been trying to fix this issue since morning through ChatGPT but StackoverFlow is saviour :P

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to login to your AWS root account with MFA code/Token number please try to set date and time correct as for me i was unable to login to my root account so i set the time zone correctly so follow the same it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the problem is that your MFA is not correct.

You need to resync the Mobile App with the present site functionalities. It is simple, All you have to do is type two authentication codes and it will auto-correct.